# Фреймворк Django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

Я недавно начал изучать Django. (Посмотрел видео курс на youtube, планирую изучить документацию) Захотелось написать что-то интересное (не просто сайт, а какой-нибудь интернет магазин и тп) 
    Так вот: не подскажете что нужно знать помимо Python и Django, чтобы без особых проблем написать подобное (ну например нужно же знать html, уметь работать с bootstrap для красивого оформления веб проекта)? Вот меня и интересует, какие технологии нужно знать кроме этого фреймворка, чтобы можно было без проблем начать свой веб проект на нем?

Comment: Знать нужно ровно столько, сколько необходимо для решения стоящей перед вами задачи.

Comment: так Вы начните делать какой-нибудь проект и поймете что еще не хватает! "On s'engage et puis… on voit."

Comment: Ну всё-таки для самого начала, кроме Python + Django что нужно знать, чтобы начать по вашему? Html то для оформления все равно понадобится, например - я вот имею ввиду такие не прямые вещи, которые нужны для успешного проекта, может из опыта что расскажете.

Comment: @FedotSoldier на Stack Overflow вопросы типа «по вашему» — неформат

Answer (score 1):

Начало здесь, продолжение смотрите по ссылке https://github.com/kamranahmedse/developer-roadmap
Ну и само собой без основных знаний английского для чтения технической литературы (читай - документации) сложно, однако очень сложно только в начале пути :)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо, я вообще не собираюсь идти в веб с головой, но написать хотя-бы один проект (свой интернет магазин очень интересным кажется) не мешало-бы для общего развития. А так спасибо за информацию!)

Answer (score 0):

Необходимый минимум - только Python, Django и HTML, а потока не существует, чем больше вы знаете, тем лучше.

Comment: Ну я это и имел ввиду - необходимый минимум. Ну а вообще - после этого минимума что изучить в нужном направлении? HTML - он для оформления нужен, кстати, или как?

Comment: Естественно. Каким ещё образом формировать пользовательский интерфейс в web-приложении?

Comment: Я просто новичок именно в веб отрасли, поэтому возникают подобные вопросы. В любом случае спасибо за информацию

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev ну ещё как минимум SVG и Flash :)

Answer (score 0):

Для разработки веб-приложений, например таких как онлайн-магазин, в большинстве случаев необходимо знать:
1)Фронтэнд (интерфейс, который видит пользователь):
    HTML,
    CSS (если не хочется сильно с этим заморачиваться, используй Bootstrap - это CSS-фреймворк с готовыми стилями элементов)
    JavaScript (ну и его фреймфорки, все перчислять смысла нет, их слишком много, выбирайте те, которые под твою задачу будут подходить)
2) Бэкэнд (бизнес-логика приложения выполняемая на сервере, обработка данных): если выбрали Python, как язык для написания серверной части вашего веб-приложения(сайта), то дальше вам стоит выбрать веб-фреймворк, например то же Django или Flask. Так же понадобится понимание СУБД и SQL.

Comment: Thanks for helping! (Не скажете, JS для какой части нужен?, пользовательский интерфейс можно же сделать и с помощью html+css или как? Я в этом просто не очень разбираюсь)

Comment: JS традиционно использовался для клиентской части (т.е. фронтэнд) - для создания анимации окошек, и прочей "динамики" сайта - автоматически меняющиеся картинки в баннерах, "выезжающие" окошки, мигающие рамочки и прочие свистелки.
Сейчас, в связи с развитием и популярностью языка JS, его можно использовать не только для клиентской части (фронтэнда), но и для серверной части сайта (бекэнда), например таким фреймворком является NodeJS.